# How to stop/terminate Argo cron workflow?

Tags: cron, kubernetes-cronjob, argo-workflows, argo, argo-cron-workflows

In our requirement we need to connect to ARGO instance and take necessary actions on the jobs.

So we are consuming ARGO java apis to connect to argo instance and performing the actions like suspend,resume,retry....

But i am not able to find apis for stopping/terminating cron jobs.

So how can i stop/terminate the cron jobs ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API for stopping/terminating cron jobs in ARGO. However, you can achieve the same using the ARGO API for getting the list of jobs and then deleting the job using the API for deleting a job.

Comment: it would delete only the list of jobs created under particular cron job , But the cron job would be still alive is it ? 
it would still create the jobs as per scheduled timings .   


How to stop the cron job itself ?

Answer (score 0):

You can terminate your Argo cron workflow using:

```
argo cron suspend CRON_WORKFLOW... [flags]
```

Check the https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/cli/argo_cron_suspend/ for more info.

The second solution would be using Argo GUI for that:

Go to the 'Cron Workflows' section, look for the Cron that you are interested in and click 'Suspend' at the top.
[Argo GUI Suspend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJkur.png)